# Row number through stored procedure

Tags: mysql, row-number

I am getting row number through SQL statement in sqlyog as follow;

```
SET @v_num:=0;
SET @v_type := 0;

SELECT  pd.event_id,
        @v_num := IF(@v_type = pd.event_id, @v_num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
        @v_type := pd.event_id AS dummy
        ,CONCAT(va.id,',',va.`firstname`,',',va.`lastname`,',',IFNULL(va.`picture`,'')) user_info
FROM p_details pd
INNER JOIN vw_all va ON pd.pass_for = va.`user_type` AND pd.attendee_id = va.`id` AND va.`pass_id` = pd.id
WHERE CURRENT_DATE() BETWEEN pd.start_date AND pd.end_date
AND pd.event_id IN (9,50) 
ORDER BY pd.event_id,pd.last_date_time DESC
```

As you know we cannot use @v and "@v_num := IF(@v_type = pd.event_id, @v_num + 1, 1)" in the stored procedure. So I am not able to get row number through mysql stored procedure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think you can not use this technique in a Stored Procedure?
Just wrap the CREATE PROCEDURE statement around your code like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testRowNum ()
BEGIN
SET @v_num:=0;
SET @v_type := 0;

SELECT  pd.event_id,
        @v_num := IF(@v_type = pd.event_id, @v_num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
        @v_type := pd.event_id AS dummy
        ,CONCAT(va.id,',',va.`firstname`,',',va.`lastname`,',',IFNULL(va.`picture`,'')) user_info
FROM p_details pd
WHERE Something = 'SomeValue';
END;
```

And your good to go already.

Comment: Now working fine but its repeating same row number (only repeating row number 1) and its showing only row number 1 twice against every event_id

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce that. I set up a small sample based on your code and it's working as expected. - But is that something that changed with using your code in a stored proc? - I guess not.

Comment: Nothing changed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Repeating values fixed through this command:

```
SELECT  tt.event_id,
        @num := IF(@type = tt.event_id, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
        @type := tt.event_id AS dummy,
        tt.info user_info
FROM (
    SELECT  pd.event_id
            ,CONCAT(va.id,',',va.`firstname`,',',va.`lastname`,',',IFNULL(va.`picture`,'')) info
    FROM p_details pd
    INNER JOIN vw_all va ON pd.pass_for = va.`user_type` AND pd.attendee_id = va.`id` AND va.`pass_id` = pd.id
    WHERE CURRENT_DATE() BETWEEN pd.start_date AND pd.end_date
    AND   pd.last_date_time IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY pd.event_id,pd.last_date_time DESC
    )tt
```